# scroll view + segment button +iOS

Tags: ios, button, uiscrollview, scrollview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have 2 scroll views. I put many buttons onto the first scroll view. When I click one button in the first scroll view, related buttons fill the second scroll view.

I want the buttons in the first scroll view to have the effect as if they are segment control. i.e. when one button is clicked, its image becomes dim and can't be clicked again until other buttons in the first scroll vew are clicked.

How to achieve this? any sample code is appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just keep track of which button was last clicked, and reset that one to be in the active state, and set the one you're now clicking to the inactive state?  Just create a property, lastClicked, and do this:

```
-(IBAction) buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.lastClicked setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.lastClicked setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"enabledImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disabledImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.lastClicked = sender;      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a segmented control inside a scroll view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    journals = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 49, 320, 29)];
    self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 29);

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width, self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height -1);
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

    self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

    [scrollView addSubview:self.segmentedControl];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    [self fillJournals];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Will value that kleopatra.

Answer (score 0):

Super simple, very ugly, but it works.  You could optimize this out further by having it check the image and the interaction state of the button, so you aren't setting an image every time this loops through.

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    for (UIButton *btn in self.scrollView.subviews) {
        if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

            if (btn == sender) {
                [btn setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
                [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disabledImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            } else {
                [btn setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"enabledImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks CodaFi so much for your super prompt and simple reply! I had thought that I have to use button tag. will back to you once I test it.

Comment: Dear CodaFi, I drag and add my buttons onto the first scroll view from library, instead of by code. when I using the following '-(IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender 
{ for (UIButton *btn in self.scrollView.subviews) {
        if (btn == sender) {
            [btn setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disabledImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else {
            [btn setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"enabledImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    } }

Comment: Following error:2012-12-10 10:26:37.028 Autoscroll[457:b603] -[UIImageView setImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b7a130
2012-12-10 10:26:37.032 Autoscroll[457:b603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b7a130'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dce5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f22313 objc_exception_throw + 44

Comment: It appears you're also adding images to the view.  You need to conditionally check the class of each of the buttons.

Comment: appreciate your further explanation. I want to use image button.